# How does Root File System works on embedded linux?

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, buildroot, rootfs

I'am learning about embedded systems, and i was able to compile and setup a SAM9x35 EK with buildroot, mounting the bootstrap, the U-Boot, the Linux and The rootfs (Buildroot's basic RFS[root file system]skeleton).
I have LOTS of questions, but one of the most important is:
Pre Question Statements, for context:

- I already have a provided JFFS2 with and app inside that is made of several NetBeans (c++) projects.
- These projects use kernel built in (if selected in buildroot's menu) libraries

**How does it work? 
How the rootfs and the netbeans (makefiles) connect to linux packages?
What I mean is, How the kernel manages the makefiles from the netbeans projects?
i.e.: If i create a project that shows a picture on the screen i add some needed packages to the rootfs and then this is flashed to the device. How the kernel knows how to read and run this app? What I have read after doing this question is that Kernel start some script in init.d folder. *But I would like a more Conceptual explanation of the interaction between Kernel and Rootfs***

Any Explanation could help me because i dont understand how exactly works. The application is a standalone application that is loaded at the start of the linux (power on) and is only that, it runs and uses hardware to go through its different functions.
Please feel free to use links or examples.

Thank you very Much.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me. Are you just asking what the steps are that the software goes through when booting the system? Or are you asking how to extracting projects from the JFFS2 image and copy it to the Buildroot-generated rootfs? Or is the JFFS2 the output of a Buildroot configuration that you got from somewhere? If so, would it be possible to point to that?

Comment: I edited the question in more detail, but i would say that: what the steps are that the software goes through when executing a standalone app inside a Rootfs file.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  The kernel, once it has booted, exists primarily to service requests from userspace.  The root filesystem exists to hold system-related information.  Userspace essentially determines what the system does.  You need to understand what the application does.  *"The application is a standalone application..."* -- So the system has a dedicated application.  Describing an application as *"standalone"* is meaningless.

Comment: May be has no sense because i am new and i dont understand how my app in the rootfs is executed by the kernel. Should i've asked, "how does and embedded system works?" Isnt that very broad? i tried to respect the policies for asking but since im noob i dont know how to ask more specfically im sorry. Still i think is very clear: "But I would like a more Conceptual explanation of the interaction between Kernel and Rootfs", may be is unusual because im not asking for code.